# How do distribution installers avoid ext2/3/4 initialization?

Tags: system-installation, ext4, ext3, ext2

When I format a volume with ext4, I have two options regarding initialization. I can either use `lazy_itable_init=1` (the default setting) to delay initialization until after the volume is first mounted, or I can use `lazy_itable_init=0` to initialize the file system immediately.

`lazy_itable_init=1` causes the hard drive to grind away for many minutes after it's first mounted, while `lazy_itable_init=0` causes the hard drive to grind immediately (during formatting) at a higher I/O rate than it does with `lazy_itable_init=1`, so it grinds for less time, but still a few minutes.

However, neither of these things happen when I'm installing a distribution (I use xubuntu, but I think it applies to all distributions). In this case, an ext4 partition, a swap partition and an EFI partition are all formatted ostensibly within about 10 seconds, and then files immediately start getting written to the ext4 partition. The whole installation process takes only slightly longer than the initialization alone when otherwise formatting a volume using `lazy_itable_init=0`. When the computer is rebooted after the installation there's no constant hard drive activity, so presumably there's been no initialization at all.

How is this possible?

Comment: IMHO you are zeroing hard disc content.